# Access object inside the array which is inside the other object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, where inside each object I have another array. I need to access the object inside that array. How do I do that?

As an example, here is my function where I log into the console each one of those arrays. And I want to console log each description instead.

```
  const var = data.filter((u) => { 
       console.log(u.array)
    })
```

And here is the JSON data

```
[
  {
    "agreed": true,
    "email": "test@test.com"
    "array": [
      {
        "name": "Alex",
        "city": "Pedro",
        "state": "WA",
        "description": "Alex was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Why are you using `filter` for simple iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet. data contains the original array then u contains each object of outer array. Then u.array.map traverses each individual array and i.description contains each sub-array's description.

```
data.map((u) => {
    u.array.map((i) => {
        console.log(i.description);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the exact index, you can do this.

```
const var = data.filter((u) => { 
       console.log(u.array[0].description)
    })
```

if you dont know the exact index, or if you wanna do this for each item in the array you can do this.

```
const var = data.filter((u) => { 
  u.array.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.description)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You index into arrays with `array[someIndex]` starting with `0` for the first item.

So you can:

```js
let arr = [{
  "agreed": true,
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "array": [{
    "name": "Alex",
    "city": "Pedro",
    "state": "WA",
    "description": "Alex was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"
  }]
}]

// get the first whole object
console.log(arr[0])

// get the arra property of the first object
console.log(arr[0].array)

// get the first object of that array
console.log(arr[0].array[0])

// get a property on that object
console.log(arr[0].array[0].name)
```

If you need to dig into an array and access of manipulate values, you can use tools like `forEach`, `reduce()`, etc. to loop over them:

```js
let arr = [{"agreed": true,"email": "test@test.com","array": [{"name": "Alex","city": "Pedro","state": "WA","description": "Alex was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"},{"name": "Mark","city": "Anchorage","state": "AK","description": "Mark is also patient. He is one of the good guys!"}]},{"agreed": true,"email": "test@test.com","array": [{"name": "Steve","city": "New York","state": "NY","description": "Steve was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"},{"name": "Nancy","city": "Anchorage","state": "AK","description": "Nancy is also patient. She is awesome!"}]}]

// log each name
arr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.array.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item.name)
    })
})

// build a new list of just the cities
let cities = arr.reduce((arr, obj) => {
    obj.array.forEach(item => {
        arr.push(item.city)
    })
    return arr
}, [])
console.log(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

if this would be the structure of your Javascript Object

```
var data =    
[
  {
    "agreed": true,
    "email": "test@test.com"
    "array": [
      {
        "name": "Alex",
        "city": "Pedro",
        "state": "WA",
        "description": "Alex was very patient. He is one of the good guys!"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then You can access the array by,

```
data[0].array[0].name;
```

And you can console.log description like this, if you are using jquery

```
$.each(data[0].array, function(i,v){
   console.log(v.description);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all descriptions to an array or just display it, like this

```
let descriptions = [];
data.map(item => item.array)
    .forEach(array => {
        array.forEach(obj => {
            console.log(obj.description);
            descriptions.push(obj.description);
        });
    });

console.log(descriptions);
```